# Check if element exists in vector R

Tags: r, seq

I am fighting with some weird behavior of R. Can someone explain what is happening?

In the following example, `check` is false in the first example, and true in the second one. Why is `seq` different to `c`?

```
by <- 0.1
percentage <- 60

probs <- seq(0,1,by)
checkValues <- probs * 100
check <- percentage %in% checkValues

probs <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)
checkValues <- probs * 100
check <- percentage %in% checkValues
```

It is getting even weirder, as if I set `by <- 0.25` and `percentage <- 75` both `check` are true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen victim to [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558):

```
p1 <- seq(0,1,0.1)
p2 <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)
> identical(p1, p2)
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(p1, p2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `check <- as.integer(probs * 100)` fixed it, thank you