# condition with "for i in vector" how to wrote condition for i not exist in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a condition that says if "i" doesn't exist in the vector print 0 - meaning in this vector it should print just [3]

```
number_vector=c(1,5,26,7,94)
for (i in numbers_vector) 
    if ((i >24)&(i%%13 == 0)) {
        print(which(numbers_vector==i))
    } else {
        print(0) 
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a loop `as.integer((number_vector > 24) & (number_vector %%13 == 0))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element exists in vector R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527925/check-if-element-exists-in-vector-r)

Comment: `v <- c(1,5,26,7,94);
which((v >24) & (v%%13 == 0))`

Comment: I was asked to do a loop, because in another vector for same code 'i' is not exist and the answer should say just [0]. my problem is that I get answer for each element in the vector instead of just [0].
[1] 0
[1] 3
[1] 0
[1] 0

Comment: `v <- c(1,5,27,7,94); w <- which((v >24) & (v%%13 == 0));
if (length(w)==0) 0 else w`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your hometask (using a loop):

```
v <- c(1, 5, 26, 7, 94)
w <- 0
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  if ((v[i] >24) & (v[i] %% 13 == 0)) { w <- i; break }
}
w
```

Without the restriction the code can be short:

```
v <- c(1,5,27,7,94)
w <- which((v >24) & (v%%13 == 0))
if (length(w)==0) w <- 0
```